# Can molecular structure be explored using sound waves? (Project Hail Mary)

Tags: acoustics, atoms

I have studied science till school, but not in grad... so I might very much be wrong ... isn't the wavelength of sound waves larger than the dimensions of atoms? Won't sound waves skip over atoms?

Comment: Yes, the wavelength of sound waves is much larger than the dimensions of atoms. Can you explain  the link to Andy Weir's science fiction novel https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Hail_Mary ?

Comment: Sure, but it will be a spoiler for the novel.
.
.
.
.
The main protagonist meets an organism from an alien species. In that species' homeworld, light is too low to be of any use for senses. Their entire sensation is sound based. However, they understand chemical elements in molecular ( & perhaps even atomic) structure.

Comment: Then presumably an inability to "see" atoms directly is no more an obstacle to the aliens than it is to us. They could have their equivalents of electron microscopes and other equipment which produce magnified sound "images" of things they cannot "see" directly.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, to get an image via ultrasound for example requires a sound wavelength that is at about 1/2 or preferably 1/10th the size of the smallest thing you wish to detect. For sound waves, there's no physical process available to make their wavelengths short enough to get images of atoms.